# How to write [[K, V]] -> {K: V} in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
fromPairs<T extends KeyValuePair<K, V>>(pairs: T[]): {[index: K]: V};
```

Of course, K would need to be constrained to a `number` or `string`, not sure how do do that either.

The error I get is:

```
Cannot find name
```

for `K` and `V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way (with a function overload):

```
declare function fromPairs<V>(pairs: {key: string; value: V; }[]): {[index: string]: V};
declare function fromPairs<V>(pairs: {key: number; value: V; }[]): {[index: number]: V};
```

It's generally not useful to have a generic 'key' type parameter in TypeScript -- `string` is almost what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an index parameter can only be either `string` or `number`, so your use of `[index: K]` is illegal.

Second, your attempt to reference type parameters in generic constraints can't be done in TypeScript, and will probably end up in a `Constraint of a type parameter cannot reference any type parameter from the same type parameter list` error.

In your case however it seems that the `T` type parameter is unnecessary, and the function can be simplified:

```
function fromPairs<K, V>(pairs: KeyValuePair<K, V>[]): {[index: string]: V}
```

Since the `index` parameter is `string` (or `number`), the `K` type parameter also becomes pointless. As a result the function can have the following signature:

```
function fromPairs<V>(pairs: KeyValuePair<any, V>[]): {[index: string]: V}
```